# Using SocketScan SDK with C# Web Service

Tags: socketscan

What I am trying to do is to call a web service using jquery (ajax json call) and use this SocketScan sdk in the web service (C# based web service). 
    As, my Mobile App uses only Jquery so I have to make use of this Socketscan sdk in the web service only.

I want to build a sample app for the same. How can I achieve this?

I have added the dll reference to my web service and can see all the methods used in dll but I am not able to understand the flow of dll.

Regards
Aman

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I understand you are trying to make use of the C# SDK in jQuery. Are you building a mobile app using something like Cordova? Is your web service running locally on the mobile device?

Comment: Yes, I am using Telerik AppBuilder. Now, what I need is to use the SocketScan SDK which is used to get data scanned using BarCode Reader hardware device.                                                                     This SDK supports C#. Have you worked on SocketScan sdk?

Comment: I'm currently working on the next version of the Android SDK, so I'm familiar with it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Telerik AppBuilder is based on Cordova, so you can't call native code directly and the ScanAPI SDK doesn't support javascript. You will need a plugin which wraps the native SDK (C#, Java or Objective-C, depending on your target platform) and exposes the functionality you need to your app. You may have to [develop a Cordova plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html), if there isn't already a plugin released under a suitable license for your app.

Comment: What about consuming this SDK in web service and calling the web service through mobile app. That is what I am trying to do. I am looking for someone who has used this SocketScan sdk in C# (preferably in web service).

Comment: Are you running the web service remotely? Or on the device?

Comment: The scanner needs to be connected to the device that's running the SDK - your web server. Unless your end-users are all 30 feet from your server, that's not going to work. If you ran your web service on the device, you app could connect to it over localhost, but it's probably easier to just write a Cordova plugin.